# Scala Swing package not found

Tags: swing, scala, import

My Problem:

```
error: object swing is not a member of package scala
import scala.swing._
^
```

When I try to start any GUI App with Scala. What I tryed up to now: call directly by the scala command, and precompile first by scalac and fsc, nothing works.

My System: an Ubuntu 11.10 Machine, with installed OpenJDK 6, OpenJDK 7, Oracle JDK 6 and the Scala-Packe from the Ubuntu Repositories, additionally I tryed the "new" Scala from the official Scala Homepage (scala-lang). The .deb-package fails to install, but the plain files from the *.tgz file works so far.

I tried every possible combination of those Software I have installed, no one works.

The Joke: on my Windows 7 Machine, the same code (dropbox-sync) works without any problems.

Any Ideas? Did I forget something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is apparently not finding `scala-swing.jar` on the classpath.  I'm not sure why this would be; it works on my system (still 11.04; don't like Unity).  Try adding it explicitly:  `-cp /wherever/oneiric-ocelot/puts/scala/lib/scala-swing.jar`.

If the file is not on your system, you can download it from the [project webpage](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing). (Click on the appropriate "latest release" buttons in the README, just under the title.  Then download the jar.)

Comment: @Hisako - That's strange.  Try `_root_.scala.swing._`?  You don't have something else shadowing the `scala` name do you?

Comment: nope, shadowing should not be the problem, scala itself works fine. _root_ doesn't work, through.

Comment: checked again that nothing in /usr/bin, /usr/local, ... is shadowing scala, also went through my $PATH, nothing there. Then I installed again the Scala package from the Ubuntu SOurces. No Solution up to now. :(

Comment: @Hisako - Try using global search for "scala-swing.jar" (locate "scala-swing.jar")

Comment: @Hisako - I don't know what else to suggest, other than to reiterate that it must not be finding `scala-swing.jar`.  I have no idea why.  (Unicode in the path name that isn't handled properly?)  Put some other jar next to scala-swing.jar and see if you can load anything from it, perhaps?

Comment: Unicode shoudn't be the problem, everything in the path consists of "true" ascii characters, nothing like the german "Ä" or the like. Its correct that simply the lib isn't found, I'll try the suggestion with the additional jar, hope it will help. :)

Comment: after many installs, deletions und poking around with some settings, i found an old scala installation in a folder i forgot. Removed, problem solved. It WAS shadowing of the scala command. Just for interest: Eclipse with the scala ide plugin works well as it seems to use it's own compiler/tools, even when the installed scala works weird.

Answer (score 18):

already many months since the original question, but since I just ran into the same, and googling showed this thread:

Looks like they separated scala swing from the core swing library. So if you're using sbt:
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.2"

(I guess the previous answers imply that as well, really, but since I got that error and this was the fix, I'm just adding it for others' reference).

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to resolve this error is to either download the scala.swing package and keep it in a folder called lib in your main project folder. this way when you compile the program uing sbt or any other tool the compiler will scan the lib folder and update itself with the new package. the other way is to edit the build.sbt file by adding the following line in it

"org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.2"